# Bar chart creation error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' "

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to create a bar chart that indicates the frequency of routes between several locations.

The y label represents the number of times a certain connection is made.
The x label represents the connections

LBB is a list that contains the list of connections between locations:
This is its format:
`[('A', '->', 'B'), ('B', '->', 'D'), ('F', '->', 'B'), ('A', '->', 'C'), ('C', '->', 'A')]`

BB is a list that contains the frequency that each of the connections in LBB happens:
This is its format:
`[1, 9, 1, 10, 64]`

Notice that every component of LBB is connected to the respective BB in the same position.

This is the code that i am using to create the chart

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   plt.bar(LBB,BB)
   plt.show()
```

The error that i get everytime is the following:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

I'm making this question because every other question i've seen online only focuses on dates on the x axis, and never on just normal text.

So if anyone could please help me i would be very thankfull!

Comment: I don't understand what the bar chart is supposed to show. The numeric values of LBB are on the x-axis, but what does the y-axis (i.e., the bar height) represent? BB is a list of tuples containing strings.

Comment: I am sorry. It's the other way around. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use tuples as categorical x-axis data but we can convert them into strings which can be easily [plotted as categorical data](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

LBB = [('A', '->', 'B'), ('B', '->', 'D'), ('F', '->', 'B'), ('A', '->', 'C'), ('C', '->', 'A')]
BB = [1, 9, 1, 10, 64]

plt.bar(["".join(b) for b in LBB], BB)
plt.show()
```

Sample output[image]: